# How to rocket jump with Axton?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is there a way to rocket jump in Borderlands 2 using Axton? I have seen several blogs and videos, and I have Badaboom + sham, but it does not work for me. Even a simple grenade jump is too much for me. Am I missing something?

Further, I am lvl 80 and yet I die at times when using a lvl 26 Badaboom, despite 86% absorbing sham shield (lvl 80).

Comment: Do you have skills that might boost your launcher damage to the point that it would kill you? If you reset your skill points and try the same jump(s), does the Badaboom still kill you?